# ORM Lite Android Create Temp Table Using Existing Table

Tags: android, ormlite

ORMLite Android doesn't use Create table statements, since its purely Object oriented. But I have a scenario to copy existing database table data to temporary database table. how can i achieve that?

Table A already contains data, I need to create table A_temp and copy all the data from Table A to table A_temp. (Table A and A_temp has same structure)

**EDIT**

I ended up with using below strategy. Thanks @gray for suggestions.

```
TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, A_Temp.class);
connectionSource.getReadWriteConnection()
            .executeStatement("INSERT INTO A_Temp SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM Table_A", 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ORMLite Android doesn't use Create table statements, since its purely Object oriented.

Well no, it does you `create table` statements.  That's what the `TableUtils.createTable(...)` calls do.

> But I have a scenario to copy existing database table data to temporary database table. how can i achieve that?

Have you tried using the [`dao.executeRaw(...)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.html#executeRaw%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29) to issue the copy commands yourself?  You then can use the `@DatabaseTable(tableName = "A_temp")` on your entities to point them to the right table.  This should work fine.